# react.js, how to create a search filter from API data?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create my first search bar in React.js. I am trying to implement search functionality with filter method. I faced a problem with filter method, which gives an error like "filter is not defined". I am stuck on it for 2 days, I have looked  several tutorials and endless youtube videos. This is the simpliest approach, I guess. Any help  will be appreciated.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Recipe from "./Recipe";
import "./styles.css";

export default function RecipeList() {
  const apiURL = "https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=c";
  const [myRecipes, setRecipes] = useState("");
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  // fetch recipe from API
  function fetchRecipes() {
    fetch(apiURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setRecipes(data.meals))
      .catch(console.log("Error"));
  }

  function onDeleteHandler(index) {
    setRecipes(
      myRecipes.filter((element, filterIndex) => index !== filterIndex)
    );
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecipes();
  }, []);

 const filterRecipes = myRecipe.meal.filter( element => {
return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
 })
{/* filter method above doesn't work */}

  return (
    <div>
       <label>
          <div className="input-group mb-3 cb-search">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Search for recipes..."
              aria-label="Recipient's username"
              aria-describedby="button-addon2"
              onChange = {e => setSearch (e.target.value)}
            />
            <div className="input-group-append">
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                type="button"
                id="button-addon2"
              >
                Search
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </label>
      <div>
        <button
          className="btn btn-info cb-button fetch-button"
          onClick={fetchRecipes}
        >
          Fetch Recipe
        </button>
        <br />
        {filterRecipes.map((element, index) => (
        <Recipe    
          key={index}
          index = {index}
          onDelete={onDeleteHandler}
          {...element}
          name = {element.strMeal} 
        />
      ))} 
      {/** name of child component */}
      {/** strMeal is the name of Recipe in API object */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

link for code [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cerf-8hiit?file=/src/RecipeList.js:0-2084)

Comment: At least so you can get past your not defined problem, myRecipe.meal looks like a typo and you wanted myRecipes.meal.  After that, your default state is an empty string which doesn't have filter on it.  A better initial state may be an empty array []

Comment: @SeamusR I made correction, now code works,  but API gives an error

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes on your code [updated code](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-mccarthy-7v0rh?file=/src/RecipeList.js)

1. `const [myRecipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);`

You should declare myRecipes as an array if u intended to use map function.

2. `const filterRecipes = myRecipe.meal.filter( element => {
   return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase())
   })`

You have the wrong variable passing through, it should be `myRecipes`

```
filterRecipes.map((element, index) => (
       <Recipe    
         key={index}
          index = {index}
          onDelete={onDeleteHandler}
          {...element}
          name = {element.strMeal} 
        />
```

3. You should check whether your filterRecipes is not undefined before you use map function.

4. Lastly, your fetch API return error which unable to setRecipes.

Comment: I agree with you. I made changes in filter function ``code`const filterRecipes =
    myRecipes.filter(element => {
      return element.strMeal.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase());
    }); ` and in map function as well, but as you said, API still return errror

Answer (score 1):

I could not resolve you task completely because of low count of information according the task, but, i think, my answer will be useful for you.

So, tthe first thing I would like to draw attention to is a *initial state* in the parameter of `useState` function. In this task it sould be as:

```
const [myRecipes, setRecipes] = useState({meals: []});
```

Because, before fetching data, React has a time to run the code, and, when it come to line 32, it see what in the **myRecipes** (*myRecipes*, not a myRecipe. Please, pay attention when you write the code) a `string` except an `array`.

And in the line 32 i recommend you to add something checking of have you resolved request of data like:

```
const filterRecipes = myRecipes.meals.length 
 ?  myRecipes.meals.filter(element => {
    return element.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase());
  });
 : []
```

And look in the data which you receive, because, i think, there are no elements with propName like *name* (element.name).

I think, i could help you as possible. If you have any questions, ask in comments. Will answer you as soon as possible. Good luck

Comment: you couldn't resolve it, because it was my bad. I did as you said with some corrections, and it worked. thank you so much